# How to edit a person's name in the new Gmail chat?

Tags: gmail, chat, gmail-contacts

Previously in Gmail chat, I was just able to click on the name of a person to edit his name. Now, the name acts as a link which opens Contacts, where the editing can happen. the old way was faster. Can I edit the names the old way somehow?

For example, here **Aardvark** is a link, and is not directly editable.

[image]

Comment: You should still be able to customize it in the contacts view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to do this directly in Gmail. More detailed instructions: Hover on the name in the chat list, then a pop-up window will appear. Click on the arrow in the lower-right corner of this window, that'll bring up the contact. You can edit the name there.

However, Google Talk *will* let you do this. Right-click on the name, and there's a "Rename" option.